# C# Autromated test - Webaii Silver Light Website radWindow Not in focus

Tags: c#, silverlight, automated-tests, webaii

Wonder if anyone can help. Im trying to automate a number of navigation tests for a silver light website. One of my tests clicks on a button which in turn opens a radWindow popup with a number of other controls on it. the problem is I can not get any details of the objects on the newly opened radWinow. If I try to all the controls to a list my code is returning the objects of the silverlight webpage in the back ground. The newly opened radWindow popup does not have a url so I can not activate/shift focus to it. Can anyone shed any light on this problem please?

Below is a copy of my code if this helps:-

```
        //List of buttons on orignal Silver Light Web page
        var buttons = _silverlightApp.Find.AllByType<TextBlock>();

        System.Drawing.Point point = new System.Drawing.Point();
        point.X = 350;
        point.Y = 280;
        //Open radWindow popup
        buttons[1].User.ClickPoint(point);

        //Wait for radWindow popup to open
        Thread.Sleep(10000);

        //Try to get a list of all the objects on the new radWindow
        var buttons1 = _silverlightApp.Find.AllByType<TextBlock>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I work for Telerik in the Test Studio and Telerik Testing Framework support group. I will try to assist you with this problem.

I think your problem is caused by not refreshing the frameworks copy of the Silverlight Visual Tree. Give this a try:

```
         //Try to get a list of all the objects on the new radWindow
        _silverlightApp.RefreshVisualTrees();
        RadWindow radW = _silverlightApp.Find.ByType<RadWindow>();
        var buttons1 = radW.Find.AllByType<TextBlock>();
```

P.S. This would be a great question to bring to the [Telerik Testing Framework support forum](http://www.telerik.com/forums/testing-framework/automation-framework).

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. Sorry its taken me so long to get back to you. I have been on holiday. Ok I tried the above code but got the following exception:-                                                   "An exception of type 'ArtOfTest.Common.Exceptions.FindElementException' occurred in ArtOfTest.WebAii.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Element Not found!

FindExpression used: 

[xamltag 'Exact' RadWindow]"

Comment: That exception means it cannot find the RadWindow popup. Are you 100% sure you're working with a RadWindow? Obtaining a copy of the VisualTree (watch this video: http://www.screencast.com/t/m7NEmJMdO ) would help us see what you're dealing with exactly. But that may be nearly impossible if you don't have Test Studio installed.